# How to recursively use afconvert in Terminal to encode FLAC files?

Tags: macos, bash, audio, terminal

AFAIK since macOS 10.13 the system built-in afconvert could encode FLAC files:

```
afconvert "input.wav" -d flac "output.flac"
```

However I couldn't figure out how to let this command to recursively convert a folder (whether nested or not) of wav or aiff files into flac (and keep the main file names intact, except the necessary extension changes).

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in *.wav; do baseFilename=`basename "${i}" .wav` && afconvert -f flac  -d flac "${i}" "${baseFilename}.flac"; done
```

Comment: You don’t actually need those curly braces; `"$i"` and ``"$baseFilename.flac"`` are good enough.